# What kind of dough do you use to make typical american donuts?

Tags: dough

What kind of dough do you use to make typical american donuts (the ones that Homer Simpson loves). I'm from Italy and I've tried using flour and baking following some tutorials but no way: is not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two major families of North American style donuts:

- Yeast raised donuts are a very sweet yeast raised dough.  ([Sample recipe](http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2010/02/homemade-glazed-doughnuts/) from Pioneer Woman blog).
- So-called "cake donuts" which are made from a quickbread like batter very similar to muffin batter, only fried instead of baked.  ([Sample recipe](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2012/01/chocolate-cake-doughnuts--make-at-home-recipe.html) for chocolate cake donuts from Serious Eats.)

If you google, you will find a multitude of donut recipes, in a wide variety of styles and levels of complexity, but almost all of them fall into one of the two groups above.

Note:  I am not sure that *The Simpsons* has ever revealed Homer's preference in donuts.

Comment: Fantastic! Your answer really helps me, I'll try the links you reported. And by the way in the doubt, I would try both! I think this would be the Homer's way too! lol

Comment: I think that even though cake donuts are nearly as common, yeast-raised are more the "canonical" donuts. If someone says just says "donut", "plain donut", or especially "glazed donut", that's probably what they mean.

Comment: @Jefromi Glazed donuts, yeast raised ones, are almost certainly the single most popular variety.  And the 2nd most canonical donut in my mind is the chocolate covered cake donut--and the phrase "old fashioned donut" means a cake type.  Personally, I love them both, but if I had to pick, well, chocolate cake donuts are very hard to beat :-)

Comment: pretty sure homer eats cake ones as yeasties are less symmetrical flatter. ...though he wouldn't turn down any (mmm uncooked frozen donuts)